# Xcode 7 #import gets "file not found"

Tags: import, frameworks, ios9, xcode7

I just upgraded to XCode 7 trying to build my app (built with XCode 6 and iOS 8 sdk) for iOS 9 but none of my frameworks like Parse and Facebook SDK is being imported.

I've included them in the build phases part of XCode but can't seem to find them when using:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

However I do get the autocomplete suggestions when typing:

```
#import <Parse.framework/>
```

Although I still get the error:

> Parse.framework/ not found

Comment: Show your *Header/Library Search Path* settings.

Comment: It was related to that, @trojanfoe - had some of my frameworks placed in a Dropbox folder with whitespace in the folder name. Copied the frameworks to my project folder and added them from there - voila! No more errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying the frameworks from a Dropbox folder to my project folder and added them via Build Phases from there - seems to have fixed it and also indicates that there was something wrong with the header/library search paths.